# How to insert lines into specific files in which a string is not present?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed, bash-scripting

I'm looking for some help with a small script.

I would like to search all files corresponding to

```
/usr/local/directadmin/data/users/*/httpd.conf
```

for the string

```
centralized.log
```

If the string is not present in a file, I would like to insert 2 lines into it.

Currently I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! grep -q centralized.log /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/*/httpd.conf ; then
sed -i '33iCustomLog /var/log/centralized.log combined' /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/*/httpd.conf && sed -i '65iCustomLog /var/log/centralized.log combined' /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/*/httpd.conf
fi
```

At the moment, if the string is not found in any of the files, the lines are inserted into all of the files, and if the string is found in at least one file, nothing happens. Can I make it so that the lines get added to all files in which the string is not present?

Comment: You need to check each file individually: the easiest way if to use a `for` loop, eg `for f in /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/*/httpd.conf ; do if ! grep -q centralized.log "$f" ; then sed -i ... "$f" ; fi ; done`.

Comment: using grep   **-v** negates the search into string not found  **-R** will search all sub-directories, if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/*/httpd.conf ; do
  if ! grep -q centralized.log "$f" ; then
    sed -i '33iCustomLog /var/log/centralized.log combined' "$f" ;
    sed -i '65iCustomLog /var/log/centralized.log combined' "$f" ;
  fi ;
done
```

You could unite both sed lines, but i kept is as close to your example as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in $(grep -l centralized.log /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/*/httpd.conf);
do
  sed -i '33iCustomLog /var/log/centralized.log combined' "$f" && \
  sed -i '65iCustomLog /var/log/centralized.log combined' "$f"
done
```

This iterates only over all files listed by `grep`. I think it's more readable this way.

EDIT: robust version

```
function dofile {
  sed -i '33iCustomLog /var/log/centralized.log combined' "$1" && \
  sed -i '65iCustomLog /var/log/centralized.log combined' "$1"
}
grep -l centralized.log /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/*/httpd.conf | while read -r; do dofile "$REPLY"; done
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448126/lambda-functions-in-bash) to understand the above better.

EDIT2: Hopefully this will satisfy @alex-stragies. Kept previous edit for the record.

```
find /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -name httpd.conf | \
xargs -L1 -I% sh -c \
"sed -i '33iCustomLog /var/log/centralized.log combined' % && sed -i '65iCustomLog /var/log/centralized.log combined' %"
```

If an user can be named with a `%` char, just change it accordingly.

Comment: Isn't first grep and second sed missing an arguement?

Comment: Indeed. Just corrected.

Comment: Once you add the #!/bin/bash line, and account for the subshell complexity/overhead, I don't think your example is better/faster/more_readable. It definitely  takes more time to explain to a bash novice.

Comment: I wanted to squeeze every tool. I didn't even know about the `-q` argument until this question. This is because I think it's better to abstract myself from the problem: instead of communicating with grep (through `-q` and `if`), I "just want" the **list of files** (for file in "special defined list").

Comment: Your solution still has the same problem as before your EDIT. Grep will choke when given too many files. The unneeded complexity of your solution has risen because you have introduced function definitions and the read built-in. And now you have an unused function littering your environment.